# How does one cross-validate a model of binomially distributed data?

Tags: cross-validation, binomial-distribution

I'm ultimately looking to apply cross-validation to a much more complicated scenario, but for now consider the simple task of leave-one-out-cross-validating logistic regression. When you compare the left-out value against its respective model's predicted value, I presume you must convert the predicted value to the probability scale, but then do you also round the predicted value so that its either 0 or 1, or leave it unrounded? Any ideas on which is the better approach (and maybe why)?

Example data and by-hand loocv of a logistic model:

```
myData = data.frame(
 x = seq(-2,2,length.out = 10)
)
myData$y = rbinom(nrow(myData),1,plogis(myData$x))

myData$preds = NA
for(i in 1:nrow(myData)){
    thisFit = glm(
        data = myData[(1:nrow(myData)!=i),]
        , formula = y~x
        , family = binomial
    )
    myData$preds[i] = predict(thisFit,newdata=myData[(1:nrow(myData)==i),])
}

myData$predsProb = plogis(myData$preds)

#one approach:
myData$squaredError1 = (myData$y - myData$predsProb)^2
SSE1 = sum(myData$squaredError1)

#alternatively:
myData$squaredError2 = (myData$y - round(myData$predsProb))^2
SSE2 = sum(myData$squaredError2)

#which is a "better" estimate of future prediction error, SSE1 or SSE2? Why?
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be wise to study proper scoring rules, which will score continuous risk predictions.  Also, make sure you want to do (expensive) leave-out-one cv instead of bootstrap or averaging multiple runs of 10-fold cv.

Take a look at the following functions in the R `rms` package: `lrm`, `validate.lrm`, `calibrate.lrm`, `val.prob` (the latter is for external validation but provides a larger set of accuracy scores).